# How to test that at least one check box is checked with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, drupal, checkbox

I am trying to set condition user select at least one language on page here is my jQuery code

```
 $(".a_orignal").click(function(){
    var checked = $(".a_orignal input:checked").length > 0;
    if (!checked){
      alert('You can select at least one Languages!!');
            return false;
            }
});
```

and my php code is :

```
print "<div id='outer_menu'>";
$value1_node = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][0]['value']);
$value2_node = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][1]['value']);
$lang=db_query("SELECT name FROM field_revision_field_language, taxonomy_term_data
 WHERE entity_id = $value1_node

AND  field_language_tid = tid
")->FetchField();
print  "<input type='checkbox' name='mychoice' value=" . $lang . " class='a_orignal' checked />";
print "<label for name=" . $lang . ">" . $lang . "</label>"; 
$lang1=db_query("SELECT name FROM field_revision_field_language, taxonomy_term_data WHERE entity_id = $value2_node AND  field_language_tid = tid")->FetchField();
print "<div id='b'>";
print  "<input type='checkbox' name='mychoice' value=" . $lang1 . " class='a' />";              print "<label for name=" .$lang1 . ">" . $lang1 . "</label>";  
print "</div>";
print "</div>";
```

When I click on last check box they alert me but value of check is hidden they are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `$('.a_orignal:checked').size()` then checked if the size is greater than 0 or not

Answer (score 0):

Do not use click event listeners on checkboxes - it could fire earlier than the change event.

Play with this sample:

```
$(".a_orignal").change(function(){
    //your change handler here
});
```

Comment: this class used in toggle function that wise  when i am click on it they change the class mean hide class show

Comment: I've answered more to the subject. Now I think that the question is not fully clear for me. Also, since you tagged the question with drupal tag and uses drupal functions in your sample, I would strongly recommend you to not write drupal code like this. You should split data and view. Also it would be better, if you read some of the howtos (depends on drupal version you use): drupal.org/writing-secure-code, https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7

Please tell us more - what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use on event instead of click event. Try following code:

```
$(".a_orignal").on( "click", function(){
    var checked = $(".a_orignal input:checked").length;
    if (!checked){
      alert('You can select at least one Languages!!');
      return false;
    }
});
```